# How to convert from 32-bit to 16-bit unsigned integers in AVX2?

Tags: c++, performance, vectorization, simd, avx2

I use `_mm256_cvtps_epi32()` to convert from 8 `float`s to 8x32-bit integers. But the goal is to get to 16-bit unsigned integers. I have 2 vectors `a0` and `a1`, each of `__m256i` type. What is the fastest way to pack them so that 16-bit equivalents of `a0` get into the lower 128 bits of the result, and equivalents of `a1` get into the higher 128 bits?

Here's what I've got so far, where `p0` and `p1` are two `__m256` vectors of 8 `float`s each:

```
const __m256i vShuffle = _mm256_setr_epi8(
  0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13);
const __m256i a0 = _mm256_cvtps_epi32(p0);
const __m256i a1 = _mm256_cvtps_epi32(p1);
const __m256i b0 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(a0, vShuffle);
const __m256i b1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(a1, vShuffle);
const __m128i c0 = _mm_or_si128(_mm256_extracti128_si256(b0, 0), _mm256_extracti128_si256(b0, 1));
const __m128i c1 = _mm_or_si128(_mm256_extracti128_si256(b1, 0), _mm256_extracti128_si256(b1, 1));
return _mm256_setr_m128i(c0, c1);
```

Comment: presumably one of the shuffle instructions would work?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I've tried `_mm256_shuffle_epi8` but it doesn't shuffle across 128-bit lanes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't test that code but it should do the trick for you:

```
__m256i tmp1 = _mm256_cvtps_epi32(p0);
__m256i tmp2 = _mm256_cvtps_epi32(p1);
tmp1 = _mm256_packus_epi32(tmp1, tmp2);
tmp1 = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(tmp1, 0xD8);
// _mm256_store_si256 this
```

Comment: Any hint on how to solve the inverse problem? Given `__m256i` unpack it into 2 `__m256` vectors of floats.